# How do japanese people write the english word "The" in Katakana?

Tags: translation, words, katakana

My nickname is **"The Wonderboy"**, my question is basically how to write that nickname in katakana.
Is it: 
**ジ**・ワンダーボーイ ?
or
**ザ**・ワンダーボーイ ?

Answer (score 5):

*The* is pronounced as /ðə/ before a consonant, and as /ði/ before a vowel. /ðə/ is closer to ザ and /ði/ is closer to ジ. ワンダーボーイ starts with a consonant ("w"), so you should use ザ.

That said, this rule is often ignored in transliteration, and you will see ザ used regardless of the following katakana on posters.